# Why might Apache Flink write files on a Windows box, but not write files on a Linux container using simple FileSink and SimpleStringEncoder?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm working with the examples provided in 'flink-training' in the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-training).  Specifically, I'm working on the 'ride-cleansing' example.

I've replaced the `PrintSinkFunction` with a simple FileSink configured as follows:

```
        FileSink fileSink =
            FileSink.forRowFormat(new Path(args[0]),
                                           new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
                             .withRollingPolicy(DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
                             .withRolloverInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                             .withInactivityInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                             .withMaxPartSize(512 * 512 * 512)
                             .build())
                    .build();
```

When I run this example on my local machine in Intellij, the expected directory are created and files are created to reflect the data streamed to the sink.

However, when I run this same example on a Linux box (on Google Colab), the directory is created, but no files are created, regardless of how long I leave it running (I've tried 10+ minutes).

On the Linux Container, I'm running the example using the gradle setup and the following command:

`./gradlew :ride-cleansing:runJavaSolution --args="/content/datastream"`

On the Windows box, I'm just executing the RideCleansingSolution 'main' with a simple 'Application' run configuration.

What might be different about my setup on the two systems that would decide whether data is written?

Comment: Could this potentially be permissions related? I.e. that one system might not require any type of permissions to write the files to the destination, but the other doesn't have the proper configuration to allow for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the files were in fact being written, I just hadn't realized they were written prefixed with '.' and hidden by default...

Answer (score 0):

it might not work, but if you set up mono develop on whatever *n*x your using and write it all in c# via Xamarin in VS.NET23 it *MIGHT* work seamlessly across all platforms and arches... but I'm just spitballing here so `_o_/'